# distributed data between the 3 lists in JSF(Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have one rawList with data. And I need distributed this list between the 3 lists. For example

```
oneList  twoList threeList
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
```

I move `item2` element to `twoList`

```
oneList  twoList threeList
  item1   item2  
  item3
  item4
  item5
```

I move `item4` element to `threeList`

```
oneList  twoList threeList
 item1   item2    item4
 item3
 item5
```

I can move by `drag`&drop, `">" "<" ">>"` button, `checkBoxs` or etc.

I faind this solution [Basic PickList](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml) But I need 3 Lists

Maybe somebody know How canI realize it?

Comment: There is not such a component, so you need to start from scratch making this effectively a question that is not suited for Stackoverflow.

Comment: See Primeface's [drag&drop components](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dnd/dataTable.xhtml) integration with `DataTable` example. You can create 3 DataTables and move items between them.